# How can I fire a Conversion Pixel / Tracking Pixel from a native iOS and/or Android app?

Tags: java, android, ios, iphone, ios7

I have a conversion pixel from an affiliate marketing company which I need fired when a sale takes place in my iOS and Android apps.  Is there a way to launch the pixel programmatically from inside the app? The pixel is in an HTML IMG SCR tag.

Comment: just use NSURLConnection to load the graphic... (for iOS)

Answer (score 0):

Usually the company will provide an SDK to do this.  If you want to fire this manually look at the URL that is called (If this is an img src tag that is probably the pixel right there).  Then just open up a connection to that URL specifically. This is the value of src="THIS IS YOUR PIXEL"

For Android you need the INTERNET permission and the code looks like this

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet call = new HttpGet(pixelUrl);
client.execute(get);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
```